# Activate XAML Storyboard on Button Click (Windows 8 Application)

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, animation

Basically, how do I activate a simple storyboard animation with a button, instead of having it play automatically? I am trying normal buttons, toggle buttons and toggle switches here, but none have worked.

I intend for an image of a door to move right upon clicking the button, and for it to move back left when clicking it again. It should repeat the behavior indefinitely when clicked.

What goes into my MainPage.xaml file.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/1.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <Image Source="Assets/RightDoor.png" x:Name="rightdoor" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="1000" Margin="276,166,-2665,-398" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="3755">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <!--<CompositeTransform x:Name="ImageTransform"/>-->
            <TransformGroup>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="rdformTranslate" X ="1" Y="1" />
                <ScaleTransform x:Name ="rdformScale" ScaleX=".25" ScaleY=".25" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

<ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Content="ToggleButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="493,572,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="ToggleBtn"/>
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="772,572,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnTest/>
<ToggleSwitch Header="ToggleSwitch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,548,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Toggled="ToggleButton"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs file

```
    private void ToggleButton(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard myStoryboard;
        myStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["rdformTranslate"];   
        myStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    private void ToggleBtn(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard myStoryboard;
        myStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["rdformTranslate"];
        myStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    private void BtnTest(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard myStoryboard;
        myStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["rdformTranslate"];
        myStoryboard.Begin();
    }
```

Resource Dictionary file...

```
<Storyboard x:Name="rdformTranslate">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rdformTranslate"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                 From="0" To="500" Duration="0:0:1"
                                 AutoReverse ="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
</Storyboard>
```

The application is capable of running, but upon clicking any buttons, it immediately "crashes". I would very much appreciate any help in resolving the problem.

---

Edit added error from comments

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code WinRT information: E_NETWORK_ERROR Additional information: Unspecified error If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: If it crashing is it giving you an error? If so please feel free to share it with us.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: E_NETWORK_ERROR

Additional information: Unspecified error

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the `Storyboard` and make it unique. I think the app crashes when you set `<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rdformTranslate">`
which is the same name of the `Storyboard`.

Also you don't need to give a name to the translation transform object to target its `X` property. Try `Storyboard.TargetProperty = "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"`. You probably don't even need to give `X` a default value since you are setting the `From` property of the `DoubleAnimation`.

You can safely replace the `<RenderTransform>...</RenderTransform>` block in your xaml with `<RenderTransform><TranslateTransform/></RenderTransform>`.